# Change googlemap marker image from database

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Is there any way to do this?

Like, i have some data in my DB, and i show this data as markers in googlemap api.

but i want to change the marker image, from the same ID from my DB.

the name and the description, is showing correctly marker by marker, but i want to change the marker image

my code:

```
  <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">


 var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://localhost/partytime/uploadedimages/davi.png',
 new google.maps.Size(50,50), 
 new google.maps.Point(0,0),
 new google.maps.Point(0,0),
 new google.maps.Size(50,50));
 var center = null;
 var map = null;
 var currentPopup;
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
 var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
 bounds.extend(pt);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: pt,
 icon: icon,
 map: map
 });
 var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content: info
 //maxWidth: 300

 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
 if (currentPopup != null) {
 currentPopup.close();
 currentPopup = null;
 }
 popup.open(map, marker);
 currentPopup = popup;
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
 map.panTo(center);
 currentPopup = null;
 });
 }
 function initMap() {
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
 zoom: 3,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
 mapTypeControl: false,
 mapTypeControlOptions: {
 style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
 },
 navigationControl: true,
 navigationControlOptions: {
 style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
 }
 });
 <?php
 }
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM localizacoes");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 $r =  explode( ',', $row['posicao'] );
 $name=$row['nome'];
 $lat = $r[0];
 $lon = $r[1];

 $dataevento = explode( '-', $row['dataevento'] );
 $ano = $dataevento[0];
 $mes = $dataevento[1];
 $dia = $dataevento[2];

 echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<h1><b>$name</b></h1>$dia-$mes-$ano');\n");
 }
 ?>    

 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
 <div id="centro">
 <div id="map">

 </div>
 </div>
 </html>
```

Note: in this code, i put a imagem from localhost...this imagem refers an ID, and i want to show each image from each id as googlemap marker icon

Comment: Note MarkerImage is depercated, use a [google.maps.Icon object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) instead. [from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#complex_icons): **Converting MarkerImage objects to type Icon**:
Until version 3.10 of the Google Maps JavaScript API, complex icons were defined as MarkerImage objects. The Icon object literal was added in version 3.10, and replaces MarkerImage from version 3.11 onwards.

Comment: See this article: [Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps: Custom Icons](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3#custom-icons) for information about how to associate marker icons with a type field from your database.

Comment: My idea is the user create the marker and choose the image, and that image appear as icon

Comment: What issues are you having implementing that?  How are you storing the image/url in your database?

Comment: yes...the images is in a url,  and the url in the database for each user mark...can i call the marker image icon when make the call function addMarker? like here ("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<h1><b>$name</b></h1>$dia-$mes-$ano')? cause i call here the lat and lng to create the marker

Comment: @geocodezip , can u help me?

Answer (score 0):

See this article: [Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps: Custom Icons](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3#custom-icons) for information about how to associate marker icons with a type field from your database.

From that article:

**Custom Icons**

> You can specify custom icons for your markers.
>
> Start by creating an associative array which associates your icons to your type strings: 'restaurant' or 'bar.' This makes the icons easy to reference later when you create markers from the XML.

```
var customIcons = {
  restaurant: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
  },
  bar: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
  }
};
```

Comment: My idea is the user create the marker and choose the image, and that image appear as icon